# Changing the font size of terminal output in perl

Tags: linux, perl, bash, terminal, font-size

How does one change the font size of terminal output created via the `print` command in `perl`? The output font color and emphasis (e.g., bold) can be changed by using functionality provided by the `Term:ANSIColor` module (available from CPAN), but I have been unable to locate a module that supports changing the font size. I suspect the solution might involve `system` calls that modify the behavior of the shell (`bash` in my case), but I am not certain which calls would be appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot. The font size is determined by the terminal emulator; it cannot be changed via control sequences.

(HISTORICALLY, some terminals supported certain VT100 control sequences to enable "double-width" and "double-height" characters. Using these modes required special handling, though -- for instance, double-height characters had to be outputted twice, once for each line --  and these modes are not supported by most modern terminal applications.)